# Extending Gnome 3 control center

Tags: gtk, controls, system, gnome, gnome-3

I just want to know if is possible to extend Gnome 3 unified control panel (also known as System Settings) with your own modules (assuming network, display, printers, etc, are modules), and how. There is no much info about yet.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you better ask [here](mailto:gnomecc-list@gnome.org), but I doubt you can do that, by plugins or something else, anyway. Better ask there.

Comment: That's explicitly “not allowed,” per the Gnome policy. External (to the core desktop) apps are supposed to provide their own controls, and honour the ones set in `gnome-control-center`/“System Settings”. The idea is to keep this (as a critical, core component) consistent and uniform. What sort of function would you want to add?

Answer (score -2):

Up to Gnome 3.0 it is possible but it is not supported. From 3.2, which was released recently, it is no longer possible.

[Source](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2011-May/msg00089.html).

Comment: Then how come *MyUnity* can do it?

Comment: @RobinJ They modified the code?